# How to use the git parameter plugin (for branches) in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to list my branches as parameter in Jenkins. It's possible in the freestyle job (using the git parameter plugin). But I don't know how to make it work inside a pipeline?

The plugin tells us they have added pipeline [support](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) but there isn't an example somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you to please go through multi-branch pipeline [plugin](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/Setup-Jenkins-Multibranch-Pipeline-and-Organization)

Let's say you have more than one branch available in GIT. Creating a multi-branch pipeline Job allows you to distinguish and run branch based Jenkins Jobs under single project.

Apart from GIT, It also support Bit-bucket, GitHub, Subversion, Mercurial, Single repository & branch.

Comment: Is something like this also possible for git tags?

Comment: Leave Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') as blank under Source Code Management. (If you have Git publisher plugin in Freestyle Job)

Comment: This will check for latest commit among all branches and build Jenkins accordingly. From here, I would like to know your exact requirement or use case to provide you with more information using GIT plugin in Free styled Jenkins Job.

Answer (score 6):

For a declarative Pipeline, you can add a git Parameter like this:

```
pipeline{
  agent any 

  parameters {
    gitParameter(
      branch: '',
      branchFilter: ".*",
      defaultValue: "",
      description: '',
      listSize: '10',
      name: 'Version',
      quickFilterEnabled: false,
      selectedValue: 'NONE',
      sortMode: 'ASCENDING_SMART',
      tagFilter: "*",
      type: 'PT_BRANCH_TAG',
      useRepository: 'git@github.com:foo/bar.git')
   }
   stages{
      stage ("echo Git Tag") {
        steps {
          echo "${params.Version}"
        }
     }
  } 
}
```

The example above will show you all branches and tags available on the repo.
if you want to display only tags, change the type to

> type: 'PT_TAG'

if you only want to show specific tags you can filter, for example, only show tags that start with "foo"

> tagFilter: "foo*"

If you want to see more details, just check out the Pipeline Syntax Generator. you will find this at:

> Sample Step -> properties -> This project is parameterised -> add Parameter -> git Parameter